# How to use nested for loop to print in reverse order

Tags: python

```
numline = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
factorial = 1
for n in numline:
        factorial = factorial * n  
        print str(n) + "!: " + str(factorial)
```

How can I use a nested for loop to print this solution in the reverse order?
So, starting from 10! to 1!

Comment: Why do you want a *nested* for loop when this can be done without a nested for loop?

Comment: `import math
math.factorial(10)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the results in a list, then output that in reverse order.

```
factorial = 1
results = []
for n in range(1,11):
    factorial = factorial * n
    results.append(factorial)
for i, item in enumerate(results[::-1]):
    print "{}! = {}".format(10-i, item)
```

Output:

```
10! = 3628800
9! = 362880
8! = 40320
7! = 5040
6! = 720
5! = 120
4! = 24
3! = 6
2! = 2
1! = 1
```